# Make a doorbell louder? Bypassing in-built amplifier

Tags: amplifier, audio, diy

I have a doorbell I'd like to make louder (existing speaker driver is ~2W).

I had an idea of intercepting the signal going into (or out of?) the amplifier chip and feeding those signals through a separate, powered amplifier to driver a higher-powered speaker.

Here is the datasheet for the amplifier:
https://datasheetspdf.com/pdf-file/935353/ChipstarMicro-electronics/CS8305E/1

Any help is appreciated!

[image]

Comment: The volume is likely set by resistors. Reverse engineer the circuit into a schematic to see if you can simply make it louder by replacing one or two resistors.

Comment: Use a bigger more efficient 4" speaker and hide it in a plastic coffee container as I did.

Comment: @TonyStewartEE75 Thanks for the comment. I considered this, but suspected I would be limited by 5W power capability of the amplifier itself.

Comment: I got at least 10 dB gain with a better speaker and same D cells battery power, if you had a 12" speaker in a large cabinet, you probably would want to turn down the volume with 5W

Comment: @Justme Thanks for the tip. I wish i knew more about how to do this properly!

Comment: More speakers in parallel makes it louder . so 4x 4" 8 ohm speakers in parallel = 2 ohms gets you 5 Watts out max at 5V

Answer (score 1):

The audio signal is available at the bypass capacitor to the inverting input of the amplifier - the node circled in red below.

[image: The top view of the PCB area around the amplifier, with the audio signal node circled in red.]

This node is also pointed to by the arrow on the application schematic below.

[image: The single-ended input application schematic with the audio signal node pointed to by the arrow.]

Whether you actually need an external amplifier or just an increase in volume is hard to tell.